# Trying to get a canvas to follow another canvas, it goes crazy

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Okay. I'm having two canvases. First canvas (rect1) is going to be moving randomly
on the gameboard. The second (zombie) is supposed to follow rect1, but it just runs all over the place. Here is the most important code which I think should be enough to spot out what is wrong.

```
var rect1={
  x:300,
  y:150,
  width:8,
  velX:3,
  velY:3
};
var zombie={
  x: 100,
  y: 100,
  width: 10,
  velX: 3,
  velY: 3
};

if (zombie.x > rect1.x){
      zombie.velX *= -1;
    }
    if (zombie.y > rect1.y){
      zombie.velY *= -1;
    }
    if (zombie.x == rect1.x){
      zombie.velX *= 0;
    }
    if (zombie.y == rect1.y){
      zombie.velY *= 0;
    }

    zombie.x+= zombie.velX;
    zombie.y+= zombie.velY;
```

Here's a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/Scrubben/easvqk6m/1/ where you can see how the zombie (in red) behaves. Sorry for having two rects and for not commenting in the jsfiddle very well but you should get the idea. If you want me to clarify or add me any more code please let me know! Thanks

Comment: Correction: You have one canvas but two different white rectangles and one red rectangle that you're drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These statements:

```
if (zombie.x > rect1.x){
  zombie.velX *= -1;
}
if (zombie.y > rect1.y){
  zombie.velY *= -1;
}
```

don't work as intended. They flip velocities only if the zombie position is smaller than the rectangle. Instead you want to flip velocities if the velocity is going in the wrong direction.

So instead it should be something like:

```
if (Math.sign(rect1.x-zombie.x)!==Math.sign(zombie.velX)){
  zombie.velX *= -1;
}
if (Math.sign(rect1.y-zombie.y)!==Math.sign(zombie.velY)){
  zombie.velY *= -1;
}
```

updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/easvqk6m/6/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're always flipping the velocity. Imagine this:

```
// Init
zombie.velX = 3;
zombie.x = 300;
rect1.velX = 3;
rect1.x = 100; // rect1 is to the left of zombie

// Frame 1
if (zombie.x > rect1.x) { // 300 > 100
  zombie.velX *= -1; // zombie.velX === -3
}
zombie.x += velX; // zombie.x === 297

// Frame 2
if (zombie.x > rect1.x) { // 297 > 100
  zombie.velX *= -1; // zombie.velX === +3
}
zombie.x += velX; // zombie.x === 300
```

And this kind of cycle repeats forever. Instead, you can use the absolute value of it's velocity to specify which direction to go.

```
if (zombie.x > rect1.x) { // We want to move zombie to the left
  zombie.velX = -Math.abs(zombie.velX);
} else { // We want to move zombie to the right
  zombie.velX = Math.abs(zombie.velX);
}
```

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, don't really know what I was thinking haha. Thanks!