# Move object towards coordinates

Tags: javascript

Lets say I have a `var speed = 2;`, `var x = 2;` and `var y = 3;`.
I want my div element `var char = document.getElementById('character');` to approach the variables X and Y. How would I do this?

Comment: directly to variable x and y.??? did you mean coordinates ?

Comment: "I do not want my div character to move directly to variable x and y" What do you mean? Do you mean you don't want it to be linear?

Comment: @MikeC I want my object to move towards the variables x and y

Comment: @Symbios So you want it to move *towards* x and y but not directly towards x and y? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @MikeC why not? it is moving to x and y so eventually it will reach point x and y. Its like walking from Point A to Point B.

Comment: @Symbios Right... So it's moving towards x and y, yes? So what do you mean by "not directly"? Do you expect it to loop around, accelerate as it gets closer, follow a path, or what? Unless you think "directly" means teleporting to x and y. That's not what I'm saying.

Comment: @MikeC oh sorry, by Not Directly I meant so it goes towards X and Y but it doesn't teleport there. It can move directly towards point X and Y, my word choice was just really bad.

Comment: @Symbios Then you might want to check out [this question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37036399/trying-to-get-a-canvas-to-follow-another-canvas-it-goes-crazy/37036640#37036640) The basic idea is you need to take the difference between where you are and where you want to go (`start.x - end.x`) then find out if that's a positive value or a negative value. Multiply your speed by -1 or 1, depending on that difference value, and you're ready to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic trigonometric functions such as `atan[2]()` can tell you the angle from “here” to “there,” and Mr. Pythagoras can supply the distance.   Whatever algorithm you wish to supply for “approach,” *(including, very specifically, any incomplete-ness or uncertainty regarding that ‘approach,’”* is of course entirely up to you . . .